# how to refresh a page after i perform a looping(updating database)

Tags: asp.net

In my code,the system will perform a looping ,updating database base,after it completely updated all the  data,it will **scriptalert** user,which data has been updated .how to refresh the page after the **scriptalert**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `location.href=location.href;` after displaying an alert message.

***Note:*** In ASP.Net, you cannot use `location.reload();` right after postback. The postback will triggers the same event again at server-side, and **you will end up with infinite loop**.

### Regular Page

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "alert('Data was updated successfully'); location.href=location.href;";

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID, script, true);
}
```

### Ajax Page

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "alert('Data was updated successfully'); location.href=location.href;";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID, script, true);
}
```

Comment: string script = "alert('Successfully Created Settlement Number: "+Settlement_No+"')"; location.href=location.href;";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert" + UniqueID, script, true);

Answer (score 0):

If you know the page the user will be on, you can use the Response.Redirect() function.

```
     Response.Redirect("http://PAGEURL")
```

You can also use Javascript's location reload()

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function reloadPage()
  {
    window.location.reload()
  }
</script>
```

From a user control you can also use Response.Redirect after updating data:

```
  Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, true)
```

This will also preserve variables you have set.

Comment: base.scriptAlert("Successfully Created Settlement Number : " + Settlement_No + "Total Fee need to pay for this Settlement Number is :" + Total_Amount);
Response.Redirect("RequestSettlement.aspx");

why this code cannot work?can you help me,thks in advance.